# Where to place helper function for 2 files?

Tags: c++

I have 4 files: f.h,f.cpp,g.h,g.cpp.
both f.h and f.cpp include g.h, but f.cpp and g.cpp have a common helper function (Note f.h doesn't need it, but it needs definitions that are in g).
At the moment I have the helper function as free standing in g.h (so that both g.cpp and f.cpp include it). However, this scares me because: 
1.Whoever includes f.h can use it freely (meaning encapsulation)
2.If he has a function that has the same name as the free function it won't compile

I'm really hoping for a solution without code duplication (it's not a big helper functions, just a few lines. It's the principle :P).

Comment: Why are you scared of #1? Are you worried someone else will use it accidentally?

Comment: I don't know if scared is the right word on my part, I was taught to provide as much encapsulation as possible, and I was hoping to be consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `g_f_private.h`. Add all the helper classes/functions/declarations in it that are used only by `f.cpp` and `g.cpp`.

`#nclude` it in `f.cpp` and `g.cpp`.

Don't expose it to the users of `f.h` and `g.h`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options

What you describe (only a few `.cpp`s need it and no one else should use it) sounds like what'd I'd call an "internal" function.

- Make a new `.h` file for this function and others like it called `internal.h` or `detail.h` or `impl.h` or something sensical.
- Put the function in `f.h` (or even a new file like above) and use a namespace to section off code that should not be used by normal users.

  ```
  namespace internal { // or "detail" or whatever
      // function here
  }
  ```

  This is what many people and open source projects do.
- If you really really don't want anything else to use this function, you can stick it as a private static member of a class and make friend only your classes.

  ```
  class PrivateFunctions {
  private:
      // static your function
      // friend your classes
  };
  ```

  I'd advise against this method though because it's uncommon, hard to change, and verbose

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I like the first idea better than the latter, but R Sahu provided a solution that seems to capture both which is why I accepted it, why do people use internal namespace and not what R sahu suggested?

Comment: I mean the obvious reason for open projects is so people can use the helper functions, just wondering if there's more to it.

Comment: It can be easier to just stick an internal function in a namespace than in a special file where you may have to remember later what files are included where and why. Easier to work with. Also, if people really want to use your function and they have the source, they're going to use it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more access control you can make it a `friend` function.

Another option is to create a new file for the helper function and include it where needed. For only one function I wouldn't do that. Depends on you future plans.

Comment: Thanks, they contain more than class though so friend function might not suit me. Why wouldn't you do it for one function?

Comment: I only would not do that because it can get messy. It can definitely be a good option. You could also duplicate the method for each class (of you have few) or declare it as a static function in each file. Again, it really depends on your code (structure) and may be also a question of taste.